# Need help executing GET after PUT function in angular

Tags: angular, httprequest, put

I created a pop up in angular that can edit a topic has name and image property and update (PUT) to the server.

After saving, my component will `GET` the topic to show on view, based on `Id` that was returned by the pop up. 
The `PUT` method here run way slower than the `GET`, result in my view can't update because it `GET` the old topic, not the updated one.

The `PUT` function is called when i close the dialog. After close i subscribe to get the topic result, and run the `GET` function.

`topic.component.ts`, `editTopic()` method is called when i click on edit button, pass in the selected topic to dialog data then to pop up. After it's closed i get the result (which is the updated topic) and `GET` the topic in the server again with the topic id.

```
  private openEditDialog(topic: Topic) {
    let dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.panelClass = 'edit-dialog-component';
    dialogConfig.width = '1027px';
    dialogConfig.height = '491.12px';
    dialogConfig.position = {top: '138px'};
    dialogConfig.data = topic;
    return dialogConfig;
  }

  public editTopic(topic: Topic): void {

    const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(EditDialogComponent, this.openEditDialog(topic));

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        if (res) {
          this.getTopicById(res.get('id').value);
        }
      },
      (err) => console.error(err)
      );
  }
```

`edit-dialog.component.ts`, `onSave` runs when i click save, post image file and topic name to server and return `FormGroup` value to display on view

```
    public onSave(): void {
      const formData = new FormData();
      let topic = { 
        id: this.topicForm.get('id').value,
        name: this.topicForm.get('title').value
      };
      formData.append('newsTopic', JSON.stringify(topic));
      if (this.file) {
        formData.append('file', this.file);
      }
      console.log(formData);
      this.topicService.updateTopicImage(formData)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.topicForm.patchValue({
            id: res.id,
            title: res.name,
            imageURL: res.image
          });
        }

      });
      this.dialogRef.close(this.topicForm);
    }
```

updateTopicImage PUT formdata to server

```
  public updateTopicImage(formData) {
    return this.httpClient.put<any>(APIurl, formData);
  }
```

i expected the `GET` to run after `PUT` because of `subscribe()` method. But it seems like both of them run at the same time (?) and `PUT` is just slower when it need to update image file. I'm not sure how to fix this, hope you guys can take a look.

Comment: Not sure who deleted my conversation with @Nilesh Kesar but the solution is to assign id to res.data.id instead of res.id simultaneously with other data, and put close() inside subscribe() so it can execute after getting the PUT result.
Don't delete conversation that has the answer, very misleading

Answer (score -1, accepted):

move the close inside the subscribe and send the id and then use that it should work because the subscribe will close when the data is finished being patched and won't close early like it is now and also the sending the id will make you not have to do another query

Comment: i  needed the other data for old code, i will update it later. But for now i keep it to try different things, since i haven't came up with a solution yet

Comment: @Soren look at my answer now try that and it should work let me know if it does or doesn't

Comment: When i tried to put close() inside subscribe(), the console logged error status 400 bad request. Is there something wrong with my data that get PUT to server? it seems fine when i do close() outside subscribe()
Edit: i also only send the id to getTopicById

Comment: are you trying to do a update or a insert in the table? because your function name is different from what your trying to do.

Comment: do it like this this.topicService.updateTopicImage(formData)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.topicForm.patchValue({
            id: res.id,
            title: res.name,
            imageURL: res.image
          });

          // I've put the return inside the response of the PUT call.
          this.dialogRef.close(this.topicForm);
        }
      });

Comment: Sorry it's a bit confusing, i need to update that. I put the close() function in there too, but it's giving me bad request error. When i tried to log the topicForm id value in close(), turns out it's an object, not a number, maybe that's the reason for the error. I get the value with topicForm.get('id').value, the value is patched with res.id, not sure how i can mess that up

Comment: the result in console.log: Object { validator: null, asyncValidator: null, _onCollectionChange: _updateRegistrations(), pristine: false, touched: true, _onDisabledChange: [], controls: {…}, valueChanges: {…}, statusChanges: {…}, status: "VALID", … }

Comment: could you replicate your code on this site https://stackblitz.com/ it will have a working ide and make it so that we can play with it and see what exactly is happening (don't need to add the actual APIs just some dummy code like a console log)

Answer (score 0):

I think your probleme come from the line

```
this.dialogRef.close(this.topicForm);
```

The probleme here is you call your PUT method on the server and doesn't wait for the response of the server before closing your popup.

Can you try with this

```
   public onSave(): void {
      const formData = new FormData();
      let topic = { 
        id: this.topicForm.get('id').value,
        name: this.topicForm.get('title').value
      };
      formData.append('newsTopic', JSON.stringify(topic));
      if (this.file) {
        formData.append('file', this.file);
      }
      console.log(formData);
      this.topicService.updateTopicImage(formData)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        if (res) {
          this.topicForm.patchValue({
            id: res.id,
            title: res.name,
            imageURL: res.image
          });

          // I've put the return inside the response of the PUT call.
          this.dialogRef.close(this.topicForm);
        }
      });
    }
```

EDIT

Change this method for this one

```
 public updateTopicImage(formData) {
    return this.httpClient.put<any>(APIurl, formData.value);
  }
```

You cannot send the FORM has it is to the API, you must send the Object inside the form to the API.

Comment: Thanks for the early reply. I've tried putting close() in subscribe() but it gives me bad request, status 400 error. I'm not sure what it is. The topic still gets updated after i refresh the page

Comment: You cannot send the FORM to your API but send the  form.value to get the object inside the form.

Comment: i'm actually just following some guide about posting Image on server like this: https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/
the code works, it's just that the GET and PUT method execute at the wrong time, not in my intention